# Event handling in multithreaded application

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm designing a stand-alone, multi-threaded application in Java.
I'm trying to choose the best event-handling solution for his project.

I have 1-3 threads generating events (e.g comm thread completes file upload), while other threads might want to be registered for notification on this event.
I want the event-generating and event listening to be as uncoupled as possible.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an [event bus](http://code.google.com/p/simpleeventbus/).

> An event bus can be thought of as a
>   replacement for the observer pattern,
>   where in the observer pattern, each
>   component is observing an observable
>   directly. In the event bus pattern,
>   each component simply subscribes to
>   the event bus and waits for its event
>   notification methods to be invoked
>   when interesting events have occurred.
>   In this way, an event bus can be
>   thought of like the observer pattern
>   with an extra layer of decoupling.

Here's a nice [presentation](http://www.canoo.com/blog/2011/02/25/screencast-gwt-event-bus-basics/) about using an event bus ins GWT. It should give you a good idea about the benefits (and it's quite funny, too).

**EDIT**

The first link is mainly given as an example. It's really not that hard implementing something similar on your own which fits your needs.

Comment: Looks very interesting. However, from the example in the website, I was not sure under which context the event handler is called (is it under the context of the publisher or the subscriber), as well as if it is possible to wait for multiple events.

Comment: It's called if any of the publishers publish an event. It's really not much different from the Observer pattern (http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer), except that it provides one more level of abstraction. Subscribers can subscribe for multiple events.

Comment: What I meant is, does the event handler method (the subscriber) is called in the context (thread) of its own module (i.e. the module, running in its own thread, subscribes a handler and goes to sleep), or is it running under the context (thread) of the module that generated the event?

Comment: I created a performance and feature comparison for a selection of available event bus implementations including Guava, MBassador and SimpleBus. The results are quite interesting. Check it out here
http://codeblock.engio.net/?p=37

Answer (score 2):

I would use ExecutorServices to manage your thread pools.  This way when you have a listener to an event, you can ensure the event is added to the right service either using a Proxy, or hande coded. e.g.

```
public void onEventOne(final Type parameter) {
    executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            wrappedListener.onEventOne(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

You can pass this listener wrapper as and be sure the event will be processed using the desired thread pool.

Using a Proxy allows you to avoid this type of boiler plate code. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a solution where each thread can register as a listener for each type of event? If so, use an event bus type solution (or a centralized observable with typed events).

If you don't need this flexibility a manager-worker setup could suffice, where the manager gets notified of events (like: "I'm finished with my job") and can fire up workers as needed.

Comment: After reading about the event bus, i'm not sure if I don't prefer a more centerlized solution (sort of a dispatcher)

Answer (score 1):

Usage of an event bus is definitely the right choise. There are various solutions out there. You can also check out MBassador https://github.com/bennidi/mbassador.

It is annotation driven, very light-weight and uses weak references (thus easy to integrate in environments where objects lifecycle management is done by a framework like spring or guice or somethign). It provides an object filtering mechanism and synchronous or asynchronous dispatch/message handling. And it's very fast!

Google Guava has an event bus as well but it uses strong references which can be a pain if you do not have full control over your object lifecycle (e.g. spring environment)

EDIT: I created a performance and feature comparison for a selection of available event bus implementations including Guava, MBassador and some more. The results are quite interesting. Check it out here
http://codeblock.engio.net/?p=37

Answer (score 0):

use command design pattern to decoupling